# Show progressbar while preparing music and increase music volume

Tags: android, service, media-player

I'm developing a radio app in which I have written `MediaPlayer` class inside Service,on button click starting and closing service to start and stop `MediaPlayer`.But in the project I'm facing two problems

1.I want to show progress while preparing music.although I have written code inside service so not able to show `ProgressBar`.

2.when we volume up then instead of music volume ringing volume is increasing.

I spent my lot time and didn't get success can any please tell me how to resolve this.Your valuable suggestion would be great appreciated.

**PlayerService.java**

```
public class PlayerService extends Service implements OnPreparedListener {
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    public PlayerService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try {
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setDataSource(Live.mUrl);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            // mVisualizerView = (VisualizerView)
            // findViewById(R.id.visualizerView);
            // mVisualizerView.link(mPlayer);

            // Start with just line renderer
            // addLineRenderer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mPlayer.start();
        return 0;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mPlayer.release();
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: PLease post what you have tried, and the problems you are having.

Comment: @MattClark I have posted code and have posted prob in 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Check out `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(ComponentName broadcastReceiver);`

Define a BroadcastReceiver that handles ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON. The recieved intent includes a single extra field, EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, containing the key event that caused the broadcast. You can use this key event to get which key was pressed.

This is just a sample code. syntax errors may be there.

```
// in onCreate of activity
registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaReceiver ); 

// later somewhere in activity.
MediaButton_Receiver mediaReceiver = new MediaButton_Receiver();

class MediaButton_Receiver implements BroadcastReceiver {
     void onReceive(Intent intent) {

          KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent)intent.getExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT); 
          if (ke .getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
               //Decrease your volume
          }
          // Similarly other key codes .......
     } 
}
```

Unregister the receiver in onPause() or onStop()